# MYSQL transpose columns(rowsto columns)

Tags: mysql

I have a table tab1 as below

```
date_part   hour_part   Country     name    Name_value
7/29/2016      0         US         abc      10.3
7/29/2016      1         US         abc      10.2
7/29/2016      2         US         abc      10
7/29/2016      0        France      xyz      2.1
7/29/2016      1        France      xyz      2.12
7/29/2016      2        France      xyz      2.18
7/29/2016      3        France      xyz      2.04
7/30/2016      7        UK          bbb      11
7/30/2016      8        UK          bbb      11.2
7/30/2016      9        UK          bbb      11.5
7/30/2016     10        UK          bbb      11.7
```

Now how to get tab2 from tab1 as below

```
date_part   hour_part    country    abc       xyz       bbb
7/29/2016   0             US       10.3     
7/29/2016   1             US       10.2     
7/29/2016   2             US       10       
7/29/2016   0           France                2.1   
7/29/2016   1           France                2.12  
7/29/2016   2           France                2.18  
7/29/2016   3           France                2.04  
7/30/2016   7           UK                               11
7/30/2016   8           UK                               11.2
7/30/2016   9           UK                               11.5
7/30/2016   10          UK                               11.7
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display in a presentation layer if that's available - much more flexible and easily scalable.

Comment: Hi su919 - can you show us what you've tried so far, and what _specific_ problems you have had? For example, have you tried a Pivot Table?

Answer (score 0):

Use a pivot query:

```
SELECT date_part,
       hour_part,
       country,
       CASE WHEN name = 'abc' THEN Name_value ELSE 0 END AS abc,
       CASE WHEN name = 'xyz' THEN Name_value ELSE 0 END AS xyz,
       CASE WHEN name = 'bbb' THEN Name_value ELSE 0 END AS bbb
FROM tab1
```

Note that you didn't tell us what values you want to use as empty placeholders in the `abc`, `xyz`, or `bbb` columns.  I used zero in the query above, but if you want nullable columns, you could have used `NULL` as well (or really any other numeric value).

Comment: Thanks @Tim, But if i have 100 values in name columns then code will be much long , any automation please

Comment: Google "dynamic pivot MySQL"